# Duplicate a section using VBA on Word 2007

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document template that has a section of text that contains a Header and a List. When I edit this section I want Word to create a new one underneath. So editing the section works like a "Add button". Is this feasible?
Currently I'm trying to use Building Blocks and with those I manage to insert this new section but I don't know how to do it when editing a currently existing section and how to insert it after the current section.

Comment: the problem is *editing a section* will occur everytime you add a new character. Could you be clearer about what you are trying to do? Explaining a bit why? You could add a button in a menu/the ribbon to add a section...

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself very clear. The template in question is intended to write meeting minutes and is composed of several sections with a header and a bulleted list. My idea is that when you add characters to an empty section (one that only has the place holder characters or has nothing) a new section gets added. This is itended for people who are writing the minutes to always have a new section to write to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick search, it seems like there is **no way to monitor events** like `keypress` (or equivalent), `onclick` or any event that could be triggered when a user is adding text to a section.
Thus, as far as i can see, you can't automatically trigger a new section when a user is adding text.

What you can do is **adding a button in a menu/in the ribbon** (depending on the version you are using) to add a new section.

Comment: That would work. How do I add the new section after all the other sections? I don't know how to do it. Sorry, my knowledge of VBA is very very basic.

Comment: if your VBA is very very basic, i advise you to have a look at some tutos to get more familiar to Word VBA (which is not the easiest one) and to think thoroughly about how you are going to handle your case. For instance, you will have to find the end of the doc >> see [here](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2008/03/identify-end-of-document-using-word-vba.html) and copy-paste your "model section" (where will you keep it?). You should have a try and be back with the code you built to ask for some help on the pieces you couldn't handle.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added a button and managed to do it using some lessons from that site. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim cbToolBar As CommandBar
  Dim cbMenuBar As CommandBarPopup
  Dim cbSuBMnu1 As CommandBarButton
  Dim strToolBar As String
  Dim iCount As Integer

  ' Replace "My Toolbar" with a name
  ' you want to use for your toolbar.
  strToolBar = "Macro Toolbar"

  ' If a toolbar of this name already exists,
  ' append a number to the end of name to
  ' differentiate one from the other.

  ' Create and display the Toolbar.
  Set cbToolBar = CommandBars.Add(Name:=strToolBar, _
     Position:=msoBarFloating)
  cbToolBar.Visible = True

  ' Create Main PopUp Menu on Toolbar.
  Set cbMenuBar = cbToolBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
  cbMenuBar.Caption = "Macros"

  ' Add a Menu Button and a Popup
  ' Menu to the "Main PopUp Menu."
  With cbMenuBar.Controls

     Set cbSuBMnu1 = .Add(Type:=msoControlButton)

  End With

  ' Set properties for the sub

  With cbSuBMnu1
     .Caption = "Change Styles"
     .Style = msoButtonCaption
     .OnAction = "ButtonAction1" ' <- Macro to run when clicked.
     .FaceId = 150

  End With

      'cbSuBMnu1.OnAction = "Tag"

      End Sub
```

Sub ButtonAction1()

'your code

end sub

I hope this helps you 
It creates a button on word menu